# Ability to filter users with onPremisesSamAccountName with Microsoft Graph API

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I would like to filter Users from Microsoft Graph API based on `onPremisesSamAccountName`, which is currently not available with Graph API.

We have the internal employee id to be stored with `onPremisesSamAccountName` variable which is present in users API of Microsoft Graph. We are trying to filter with `onPremisesSamAccountName` property to filter based on the internal employee id. Currently, we are not able to do that with Graph API but we really need this to be working or would be happy if we get to know any possible workarounds.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=onPremisesSamAccountName eq '[some-id]'&$select= userPrincipalName,displayName,department,jobTitle,companyName,onPremisesSamAccountName,....[more list of fields for select]
```

The expected outcome is to show the required result but the response what we got is as follows:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Request_UnsupportedQuery",
        "message": "Unsupported or invalid query filter clause specified for property 'onPremisesSamAccountName' of resource 'User'.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "[request-id from request]",
            "date": "[date on which request is made]"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see, the filter is not supported for property 'onPremisesSamAccountName'.

If you do have this requirement, you can post your idea at [Microsoft Graph UserVoice](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests).

Comment: Hoping that the ability will be added as earlier as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do a filter using onPremisesUserPrincipalName - you could check what is returned using this property and see if you can make it work